# Outpost Firewall asks every time one specific application tries to access to network

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

One of installed applications on my PC tries to send UDP packed.

Outpost warns me about this. I say that Outpost should allow all activity for this application.

But next time application wants to send UDP packed Outpost asks me again and again the same question.

There is no problems with other applications but with this only.

Is it possible to resolve such behavior or is it known bug?

I have installed Outpost Firewall Pro 2009 Version 6.5.3 (2518.381.0686)

Comment: What is the application?

Comment: @John T: It is a application for authorization when connecting to the internet of my provider. It is under Vista.

Answer (score 0):

OMG I hated that problem! I couldn't figure out why it did it until I started using Comodo and it would do the same thing.

You have to go into the application and specifically allow the program.

Comment: Check out "5.3.2 Managing Rules for Applications"

From this pdf http://dl2.agnitum.com/docs/security-suite/OSS_User_Guide_EN.pdf